# Flat galaxy formation in a spherical dark matter halo

Tags: dark-matter

The dark matter halo of our own galaxy is assumed to be spherically symmetric. This sounds reasonable, since dark matter interacts gravitationally. However, stars in our galaxy are on a flat disk. Could someone explain what makes the stars stay on the disk while most of the dark matter doesn't?

Comment: Consider how a particles allowed interactions allow for energy exchange for dark and luminous matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most stars are distributed in a disk because they formed from gas that was already in a disk.

The gas collapses to a disk because when a spherical cloud with kinetic energy and angular momentum interacts with itself, via turbulence and friction, it is heated and the radiation it subsequently emits takes away kinetic energy but very little angular momentum.

As a result the gas collapses to a shape that minimises kinetic energy whilst maintaining angular momentum - a disk. The gas that has been concentrated into a disk then begins to form stars.

Stars that formed whilst the gas was still in a spherical distribution are *still* distributed spherically. These early stars are called halo stars.

Dark matter does not collapse to a disk because it has no equivalent mechanism to lose kinetic energy since, by definition, it emits no radiation.